# Keycloak SAML integration

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, keycloak, siteminder

I am new to Keycloak and need to integrate with an external system that holds information about Users and Groups (Siteminder which is working as Identity Provider). Siteminder will send us the SAML message, we will need to create user and groups based on information in the SAML message. Don't know what are the correct steps to set up Keycloak - do we need to create a client and/or add Identity Provider?

Is there a complete tutorial on how to do it?

Comment: Probably you want to use https://www.keycloak.org/docs/6.0/server_admin/#_identity_broker

Answer (score 0):

You can find here detailed instructions how to integrate Keycloak with external SAML Providers: https://ultimatesecurity.pro/tags/saml/